# Regarding path generation algorithms

Tags: algorithm, traversal

I need to set up a 2 dimensional space (for all practical purposes, a 2-D array) of paths..
Every index [y][x] contains a path..such as

```
+--  --+   +--  --+
|  ||  |   |  ||  |
|  | ==     ==++== 
|  ||  |   |      |
+--  --+   +------+
```

While I can initialize this space randomly, I want to be able to generate a sequence of paths that ensures that every coordinate can be reached from every other coordinate.

What algorithm should I be looking at to solve this?

I've learnt many path ***finding*** algorithms such as Dijkstra’s or A*, but I don't think these are usable for my problem.

Comment: brute force method is to solve the maze like a kid. start at the opening and draw a line to every area without lifting the pen. if there's any unpainted areas after you exhausted all the path possibilities, you've got an unreachable area.

Comment: I was looking for any approach better than brute force.
Brute force I think will work out to be O(n^2)

Comment: You want a [maze generation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm)? Well, there you go.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in that image? Also, `"Every index [y][x] contains a path"` - each cell contains **an entire path**?

Comment: Those are individual cells, they have paths in the form of a T or a horizontal T.

Comment: So ... the cells look similar to [Pipe Mania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_Mania)?

Comment: Yes, I believe they do look similar to Pipe Mania.
Each of the squares is one 'cell'
I need to generate a space of roughly 10x10 such cells with a condition that every cell must be traversable.
I was wondering how to go about doing that without intense backtracking

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is essentially equivalent to finding a [spanning tree](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree), which can be done in O(n) using either Depth-First Search or Breadth-First Search.

Hint: Note that if A is reachable from B and B is reachable from C, then A is reachable from C (transitivity); also as long as you don't have one way corridor then if A is reachable from B then B is also reachable from A (reflexivity).

For generating maze, once you generated a span, then you may start adding extra edges to add some variation (though extra edges usually makes the maze easier to solve). The span guarantees the connectivity.